# Is it possible to grant a stored procedure execution rights that the user executing it does not have

Tags: sql-server, azure, stored-procedures, permissions

I want to limit the number of times a certain user can execute a stored procedure per hour. To this end I am trying to use the performance stats to determine how many times the stored procedure has been executed in the last hour. If its 0 then I will allow the query in the stored procedureto be executed otherwise it skips it.

1. I create a user access to an Azure SQL Server database (not master just the DB itself):

   ```
   CREATE USER sp_only_user WITH PASSWORD = 'blabla12345!@#$'
   ```
2. I only grant them permission to execute a specific stored procedure:

   ```
   GRANT EXECUTE ON OBJECT::sp_Get_Clients to sp_only_user
   ```
3. Now I want this stored procedure to execute either a performance stats query or a function to get performance stats (whatever is easier) in order to find out if the stored procedure has been executed in the last hour. The user does not have rights to access performance stats or execute the function directly. How do I give the stored procedure such rights without giving them to the user?

This would be the performance stats query I was referring to, which I don't want the user to be able to execute directly:

```
SELECT 
    @LastExecutionTime=  PS.last_execution_time
FROM 
    sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats PS 
INNER JOIN 
    sys.objects o ON O.[object_id] = PS.[object_id] 
WHERE
    name = 'sp_Get_Clients'
```

Alternatively, I can put the query in a function and return the number of times it has been executed :

```
SELECT
    @ExecutionCntPerHour = dbo.fn_CountSpExecutionsPerHour('sp_Get_Clients')
```

Bottom line is that I need the SP to have rights that the user does not (unless of course there is a different way to limit the number of times the stored procedure is executed per hour which is easier).

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: I would, personally, suggest using a bespoke logging process and then check if there have been *x* executions in the last hour; if thetr are `THROW` and error or something. If not, run the process and log that it's been run.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Erland has a discussion on [packaging permissions](https://www.sommarskog.se/grantperm.html) that might be useful - if complex. But I agree with Larnu - a trivial bit of logging seems to be all you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, I would suggest using some basic logging.
Firstly, let's set up the tables that would be needed with minimal columns:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.ExecutionLimit (ProcedureSchema sysname NOT NULL,
                                 ProcedureName sysname NOT NULL,
                                 UserName sysname NOT NULL,
                                 ExecutionLimit int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT CK_ExecutionLimitMin CHECK (ExecutionLimit > 0),
                                 ExecutionTimeFrame int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT CK_ExecutionTimeFrameMin CHECK (ExecutionTimeFrame > 0), --This is in minutes, but you could use something else
                                 CONSTRAINT PK_ExecutionLimit_ProcedureUser PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(ProcedureSchema, ProcedureName, UserName));
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.ProcedureExecution (ProcedureSchema sysname NOT NULL,
                                     ProcedureName sysname NOT NULL,
                                     UserName sysname NOT NULL,
                                     ExecutionTime datetime2(1) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_ExecutionTime DEFAULT SYSDATETIME());
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX CI_ProcedureExecution ON dbo.ProcedureExecution (ExecutionTime,ProcedureSchema,ProcedureName,UserName);
```

Indexing is going to be important here, if you want a performant solution, as well as some kind of clean up process is you need it.

Then I'm going to create a couple of `USER`s and give one of them an execution limit (note that the procedure isn't created yet, but that's fine here):

```sql
CREATE USER SomeUser WITHOUT LOGIN;
CREATE USER AnotherUser WITHOUT LOGIN;
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.ExecutionLimit (ProcedureSchema,ProcedureName,UserName,ExecutionLimit,ExecutionTimeFrame)
VALUES(N'dbo',N'SomeProcedure',N'SomeUser',5, 60); --No more than 5 times in an hour
```

So `SomeUser` can only run the procedure 5 times within an hour interval, but `AnotherUser` can run it as often as they want (due to having no entry).

Now for the procedure. Here, you'll want to use an `EXISTS` to check if too many executions have been done within the procedure. As I mentioned, if too many executions have occured then I would `THROW` an error; I just use a generic one here, but you may want some more complex logic here. note I use `ROWLOCK` here to stop multiple simultaneous executions pushing over the limit; if this isn't likely to occur, you can remove that hint.

Then, after the check, I `INSERT` a  row into the log, and `COMMIT`, so that the `ROWLOCK` is released. Then your procedure code can go afterwards.

```sql
CREATE PROC dbo.SomeProcedure AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET XACT_ABORT ON;
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
        
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM dbo.ExecutionLimit EL
                    --Using ROWLOCK to stop simultaneous executions, this is optional
                    JOIN dbo.ProcedureExecution PE WITH (ROWLOCK) ON EL.ProcedureSchema = PE.ProcedureSchema
                                                                 AND EL.ProcedureName = PE.ProcedureName
                                                                 AND EL.UserName = PE.UserName
                                                                 AND DATEADD(MINUTE,-EL.ExecutionTimeFrame,SYSDATETIME()) <= PE.ExecutionTime
               WHERE EL.UserName = USER_NAME()
                 AND EL.ProcedureSchema = N'dbo'
                 AND EL.ProcedureName = N'SomeProcedure'
               GROUP BY EL.ExecutionLimit --Needs to be, or will error
               HAVING COUNT(PE.ExecutionTime) >= EL.ExecutionLimit) BEGIN

        DECLARE @Message nvarchar(2047);
        SELECT @Message = FORMATMESSAGE(N'The maximum number of executions (%i) within your allotted timeframe (%i minutes) has been reached. Please try again later.', EL.ExecutionLimit, EL.ExecutionTimeFrame)
        FROM dbo.ExecutionLimit EL
        WHERE EL.UserName = USER_NAME()
          AND EL.ProcedureSchema = N'dbo'
          AND EL.ProcedureName = N'SomeProcedure';

        THROW 62462, @Message, 16;
    END;

    INSERT INTO dbo.ProcedureExecution (ProcedureSchema, ProcedureName, UserName)
    VALUES(N'dbo',N'SomeProcedure',USER_NAME());
    COMMIT;

    --Do the stuff
    PRINT N'Congratulations! You have run the procedure! :)'; --Obviously this wouldn't be in there.

END;
GO
```

You can then test (and clean up) the set up with the following:

```sql
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.SomeProcedure TO SomeUser,AnotherUser;

GO

EXECUTE AS USER = 'SomeUser';
GO

EXECUTE dbo.SomeProcedure;

GO 6

REVERT;
GO

EXECUTE AS USER = 'AnotherUser';
GO

EXECUTE dbo.SomeProcedure;

GO 6

REVERT;
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.ExecutionLimit;
DROP TABLE dbo.ProcedureExecution;
DROP PROC dbo.SomeProcedure;

GO
DROP USER SomeUser;
DROP USER AnotherUser;
```

---

If this is something you need in a lot of procedures (and the design I have here allows this) you might find it better to use a procedure to check, and `THROW` the error:

```sql
CREATE PROC dbo.CheckExecutions @Username sysname, @ProcedureSchema sysname, @ProcedureName sysname AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET XACT_ABORT ON;
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
        
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM dbo.ExecutionLimit EL
                    --Using ROWLOCK to stop simultaneous executions, this is optional
                    JOIN dbo.ProcedureExecution PE WITH (ROWLOCK) ON EL.ProcedureSchema = PE.ProcedureSchema
                                                                 AND EL.ProcedureName = PE.ProcedureName
                                                                 AND EL.UserName = PE.UserName
                                                                 AND DATEADD(MINUTE,-EL.ExecutionTimeFrame,SYSDATETIME()) <= PE.ExecutionTime
               WHERE EL.UserName = @Username
                 AND EL.ProcedureSchema = @ProcedureSchema
                 AND EL.ProcedureName = @ProcedureName
               GROUP BY EL.ExecutionLimit --Needs to be, or will error
               HAVING COUNT(PE.ExecutionTime) >= EL.ExecutionLimit) BEGIN

        DECLARE @Message nvarchar(2047);
        SELECT @Message = FORMATMESSAGE(N'The maximum number of executions (%i) within your allotted timeframe (%i minutes) has been reached on the procedure ''%s.%s''. Please try again later.', EL.ExecutionLimit, EL.ExecutionTimeFrame, EL.ProcedureSchema, EL.ProcedureName)
        FROM dbo.ExecutionLimit EL
        WHERE EL.UserName = @Username
          AND EL.ProcedureSchema = @ProcedureSchema
          AND EL.ProcedureName = @ProcedureName;

        THROW 62462, @Message, 16;
    END;
    
    INSERT INTO dbo.ProcedureExecution (UserName, ProcedureSchema, ProcedureName)
    VALUES(@UserName, @ProcedureSchema, @ProcedureName);
    COMMIT;
END
GO

CREATE PROC dbo.SomeProcedure AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET XACT_ABORT ON;
    DECLARE @UserName sysname = USER_NAME();
    EXEC dbo.CheckExecutions @UserName, N'dbo', N'SomeProcedure';

    --Do the stuff
    PRINT N'Congratulations! You have run the procedure! :)'; --Obviously this wouldn't be in there.

END;
GO
```